# How to cache results for autosuggest component?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http, caching

I have a UI autosuggest component that performs an AJAX request as user types. For example, if user types `mel`, the response could be:

```
{
  suggestions: [{
    id: 18,
    suggestion: 'Melbourne'
  }, {
    id: 7,
    suggestion: 'East Melbourne'
  }, {
    id: 123,
    suggestion: 'North Melbourne'
  }]
}
```

The UI component implements client side caching. So, if user now clicks <kbd>b</kbd> (results for `melb` are retrieved), and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the browser already has results for `mel` in memory, so they are immediately available. In other words, every client makes at most one AJAX call for every given input.

Now, I'd like to add server side caching on top of this. So, if one client performs an AJAX call for `mel`, and let's say there is some heavy computation going on to prepare the response, other clients would be getting the results without executing this heavy computation again.

I could simply have a hash of queries and results, but I'm not sure that this is the most optimal way to achieve this (memory concerns). There are ~20000 suggestions in the data set.

What would be the best way to implement the server side caching?

Comment: Your options will be determined by the OS, preferred language, and ability to add modules/software if you don't wish to roll your own from the ground up.  With C# you can utilize OutputCache with VaryByParam.  On linux with php I've utilized Sphinx Search to cache my database calls specifically for auto suggest boxes.

Comment: you could just throw them in a db and let the dbms do the caching and optimization.

Comment: Is this server code always going to run in a single process on a single machine?  If not, the answers will be very different.

Comment: @AaronDufour Yes, assume single process and single machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement a simple cache with an LRU (least recently used) discard algorithm. Basically, set a few thresholds (for example: 100,000 items, 1 GB) and then discard the least recently used item (i.e., the item that is in cache but was last accessed longer ago than any of the other ones). This actually works pretty well, and I'm sure you can use [an existing Node.js package out there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache).

If you're going to be building a service that has multiple frontend servers, it might be easier and simpler to just set up [memcached](http://memcached.org/) on a server (or even put it on a frontend server if you have a relatively low load on your server). It's got an extremely simple TCP/IP protocol and there's [memcached clients](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached) available for Node.js.

Memcached is easy to set up and will scale for a very long time. Keeping the cache on separate servers also has the potential benefit of speeding up requests for all frontend instances, even the ones that have not received a particular request before.

No matter what you choose to do, I would recommend keeping the caching out of the process that serves the requests. That makes it easy to just kill the cache if you have caching issues or need to free up memory for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

> (memory concerns). There are ~20000 suggestions in the data set.

20,000 results? Have you thought about home much memory that will actually take? My response is assuming you're talking about 20,000 short strings as presented in the example. I feel like you're optimizing for a problem you don't have yet.

If you're talking about a reasonably static piece of data, just keep it in memory. Even if you want to store it in a database, just keep it in memory. Refresh it periodically if you must.

If it's not static, just try and read it from the database on every request first. Databases have query caches and will chew through a 100KB table for breakfast.

Once you're actually getting enough hits for this to become an actual issue, don't cache it yourself. I have found that if you actually have a real need for a cache other people have written it [better than you would have](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache). But if you really need one, go for an external one like Memcached or even something like Redis. Keeping that stuff external can makes testing and scalability a heap easier.

But you'll know when you actually need a cache.